# Method chaining in php behaves strange

Tags: php

I have coded a function in php to understand how the method chaining works in php. But it doesnt show me anything as an output.

My code is:

```
class sample {

function something($array) {

    $samples = array();
    foreach($array as $key=>$value) {

        $this->$key = $value;
        return $key;
    }
}
}

$hot = new sample();
$hot->something(array('maths'=>'12','science'=>'10'));

echo $hot->something()->maths;
?>
```

When I run this code I didn't get any output.I got an warning like `Warning: Missing argument 1 for sample::something(), called in /web/com/13987442563085/main.php on line 22 and defined in /web/com/13987442563085/main.php on line 10 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

My expected output here is `1`.

Hope you guys can help me in finding the right output. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First, you're passing an array to an undefined constructor.

Comment: It behaves strangely because the code is very strange.

Comment: OOps sorry .....its my mistake ...

Comment: **Method chaining ?**  There is just one method on your class. You need atleast two methods to chain.

Comment: Curious doubt - In `$this->$key = $value;` wouldn't `number` and `subject` be undeclared variables as in `$this->number` and `$this->subject`?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran i have redited the question

Comment: @user3583735 You're passing an array to the constructor but don't have a constructor defined in your class. That is what the error is telling you.

Comment: To accomplish method chaining you must return the object, in PHP's case that would be `$this`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code makes little sense from front to back.

You are calling `$hot->something()` without any parameter – and then you are wondering abut an error message telling you exactly that?

And using `return` in the foreach loop like that breaks out of it (and the whole method) in the first loop iteration.

And you can not “chain” anything here (apart from what you want not actually being “method chaining”, since you are not calling multiple methods in succession here), because your method has no return value. If you want to be able to *access a property* of the object “on” the result of the method call (or call another method, for that matter), then you have to *return* the object:

```
class Sample {
  function something($array) {
    foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
        $this->$key = $value;
    }
    return $this;
  }
}

$hot = new Sample();
echo $hot->something(array('maths'=>'12','science'=>'10'))->maths;
```

*This* will output `12`. (It doesn’t make a lot of sense still.)

Comment: I have a doubt regarding `$this->$key = $value;` Could you please help me understand it? Refer to the comments in the question section

Comment: well ..thanks and this was the output i wanted ...i just tried to do it via method chaining process and you did this via method chaining correctly ..Thanks ..

Comment: @asprin: Class members don’t have to be explicitly declared in PHP, using `$this->foo = 'bar'` will create `foo` (with public visibility) on the fly if it was not declared explicitly previously.

Comment: Thanks. But don't you mean `$this->foo = 'bar' will create foo` instead of `$this->foo = 'bar' will create bar`? i.e `$foo` will be equal to `bar`

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. (Edited my previous comment so as to not confuse anybody any further.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this on

```
<?php
class sample {



  function something($array) {

$samples = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {

 $this->$key = $value;
 return $value;
}
 }
}

$hot = new sample();
echo $hot->something(array('number'=>'1','subject'=>'maths'));
?>
```